# WCF and inactivity timeout: is it possible to disable the inactivity timeout?

Tags: wcf, timeout

I have a service that would be running forever, without matter if there is clients or not that access to this service, but after a long time without clients activity, to be able to connect with a client.

This is because for example, after a vacation period, I would like to be able to connect with the service without the needed to restart the service manually.

At the moment, my service is disconnected if it does not receive any connection in 10 minutes, but I don't want to specify any time, I want infinite time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `inactivityTimeout="infinite"`, or a very high value, though It's not recommended, your service shouldn't be such that once a client connects to it they can consume it 'forever'.

**UPDATE**

My mistake, it seems `inactivityTimeout` can not be set to infinite like other Timeouts such as `receiveTimeout`.

But why don't you just set `receiveTimeout="infinite"` ? `inactivityTimeout` is only used when you have `reliableSession` enabled, if you don't need reliable sessions, then simply set the `receiveTimeout` on the binding to infinite, in this case your `receiveTimeout` is in a way your inactivity timeout. If you must use reliable sessions, then WCF will use both values to determine when your service times out, and both need to be satisfied to keep the connection alive. It seems that the maximum value for `inactivityTimeout` is '24.20:31:23.6470000', basically 24 days and 20.5 hours, so in the worst case scenario just set your `inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23"` which is still a pretty long time, almost a month. If you send your service a simple keep alive message (basically just invoke some operation on your service) in between that period, your connection will be maintained.

Comment: i can't use the infinite value, it is not valid.

Comment: Don't have 'inactivityTimeout' as binding attribute in app.config

Comment: @KomalJariwala please refer this [WCF-Reliable-Sessions-Bindings-service-and-client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/749527/WCF-Reliable-Sessions-Bindings-service-and-client). you need to use reliableSession child tag in binding

Answer (score 1):

I fix this with:

1. Method to ping from client to server to keep the connection active for each 30 seconds.\
2. On server binding, `ReceiveTimeout` with 1 minute.
3. For each callback created a `ICommunicationObject`, using the Closed event to remove the inactive client.

```
    //Adding a client callback
    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
    ICallback callback = context.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();
    ICommunicationObject obj = (ICommunicationObject)callback;
    obj.Closed += new EventHandler(obj_Closed);

    //Event for inactive clients
    void obj_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (_callbacks.ContainsValue(((ITecnobelRemoteServiceCallback)sender)))
                {
                    var item = _callbacks.First(kvp => kvp.Value == (ITecnobelRemoteServiceCallback)sender));
                    _callbacks.Remove(item.Key);
                    treeViewClients.Nodes.RemoveByKey(item.Key.Id);
                    treeViewClients.Refresh();
                    _registeredUsers--;
                    listBoxStatus.Items.Add(String.Format("User {0} was inactive 
    and was removed", item.Key.Id));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about other version of .NET, but on 4.5 I was also trying to get around the inactivity period for a WCF service.

On a whim, I set `binding.ReceiveTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan`, which is a negative timespan.  This caused an exception to be thrown with the following interesting tidbit of a message:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Timeout must be greater than or equal to TimeSpan.Zero. To disable timeout, specify TimeSpan.MaxValue.
```

So I went back to my code, set the `ReceiveTimeout` to `TimeSpan.MaxValue`, and the inactivity timer is now disabled.